# Angular orderby sorting in loaded orders

Tags: angularjs

By using ng-repeat i'm getting values but i need to sort it in specific order.

that is 'Portfolio', 'Sourcing', 'Delinquency'

can you please help me by providing sorting order.

HTML:

```
ng-repeat="row in DashboardFilter2" | orderBy: ['Portfolio', 'Sourcing', 'Delinquency']
```

js:

```
App.createList({
            "qDef": {
                    "qFieldDefs": %Type
            },
            "qInitialDataFetch": [
                    {
                            "qHeight": 20,
                            "qWidth": 1
                    }
            ],
        },function Show2(reply, app){    
             $scope.DashboardFilter2 = app.field("%Type").getData();

               });
```

Comment: How often this array is changing through page life time?

Comment: it will changing

Comment: Would be awesome if you mention some cases when it will changes and what is triggering this change

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` looks correct to me.

Would be good to see `app.field("%Type").getData()` result.

But to be honest, I would not use `orderBy` with strong reason since it is a `filter` and evaluates on every `$digest/$apply`.

Instead, I'd sort as I want in JS before putting it into template using `Array.sort` or similar method (lodash, underscore).

If the array changes after initialization then just make a function `sortArrayYouWant` and call every time it changes.

The global idea is **NOT TO USE ORDERBY** since it is extremely inefficient

Comment: rows: Array(3)
0: e
$$hashKey: "object:87"
field: r {qapp: w, fldname: "%Type", statename: undefined, rows: Array(3), OnData: n, …}
qElemNumber: 2
qFrequency: "1"
qState: "S"
qText: "Delinquency"
__proto__: Object
1: e
$$hashKey: "object:88"
field: r {qapp: w, fldname: "%Type", statename: undefined, rows: Array(3), OnData: n, …}
qElemNumber: 0
qState: "X"
qText: "Portfolio"
__proto__: Object
2: e
$$hashKey: "object:89"
field: r {qapp: w, fldname: "%Type", statename: undefined, rows: Array(3), OnData: n, …}
qElemNumber: 1
qState: "X"
qText: "Sourcing"
__proto__: Object

Comment: As I see from your comment it returns object with `rows` insides, so probably you need this `$scope.DashboardFilter2 = app.field("%Type").getData().rows`

Comment: Or if this is async method than you might use `getData().then(result => result.rows)` or access `.rows` in ng-repeat